# SQL query to get Average of sum with group by

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, average

I need to calculate Avg. hours worked per week by employee for group of employees. Data I have is timeinseconds, empID, Dept. worked and date worked.
Something like this:

```
PName  EmpID  DeptLoc DeptName TimeinSec  ApplyDate

JRoyce  12345  900    10569    17820      2012-05-10 00:00:00.000
```

I have this query to get totalhrs by week. But I can't figure out how to get avg. hours by empid by week. Any help is appreciated:

```
select PName, EmpID, DeptLoc, DeptName, Sum(timeinsec/3600.0) as Totalhrs, (Datepart(WK,applydate))
 from EmpTable
Group by PName, EmpID, DeptLoc, DeptName, (Datepart(WK,ApplyDate))
Order by EmpID, WeekNo
```

It gives me the results I want for TotalHrs:

```
EmpName   EmpID  DeptLoc   DeptID  TotalHrs WeekNo

JRoyce    12345  900       10569   14.9166  27
JRoyce    12345  900       10569   18.0666  28
```

Now I want to group these by Avg hours by empID by week so that it shows Avg hours worked for week 27, week 28 etc.

I tried to use innerquery but it gave me avg of all TotalHrs.

Comment: What do you mean by `Avg hours worked for week 27, week 28 etc` ? Avg hours worked by day ?

Comment: Thanks everyone. but it gave me daily avg instead of weekly. I want to see avg. hours worked per week. E.g. if daily total hours for the week were 14.9166
18.0666
14.9166
18.0666
14.9166
The weekly average hrs shows 16.7666

Answer (score 0):

Divide the total hours by the numer of days worked in the week. See the AvgHours calculation in the following.

```
select  PName
        , EmpID
        , DeptLoc
        , DeptName
        , Sum(timeinsec/3600.0) as Totalhrs
        , Sum(timeinsec/3600.0) / Count(applydate) as AvgHours
        , (Datepart(WK,applydate))
from EmpTable
Group by 
        PName
        , EmpID
        , DeptLoc
        , DeptName
        , (Datepart(WK,ApplyDate))
Order by 
        EmpID
        , WeekNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.PName, a.DeptLoc, a.DeptName, (Datepart(WK,ApplyDate)) [Week], Avg(Totalhrs) as Avghrs
FROM(
select PName, EmpID, DeptLoc, DeptName, Sum(timeinsec/3600.0) as Totalhrs, (Datepart(WK,applydate))
 from EmpTable
Group by PName, EmpID, DeptLoc, DeptName, (Datepart(WK,ApplyDate))
) a
GROUP by a.PName, a.DeptLoc, a.DeptName, (Datepart(WK,ApplyDate))
```

Comment: Hi Sev, When I try this subquery, I get Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "Emptable.PNAME" could not be bound. Internal query works fine.

Comment: Made some changes.  Try that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the average hours per week, remove the `empid` from the `group by`:

```
select Datepart(WK,applydate) as weeknum,
       Sum(timeinsec/3600.0) as Totalhrs / count(distinct empid) as avgHrsPerEmployee
from EmpTable
Group by Datepart(WK,ApplyDate)
Order by WeekNum;
```

The average is determined by summing up all the time and dividing by the number of employees.